# Looking for a good source for Financial Statements

Tags: investing, yahoo-finance, financial-statements

I am looking for a good source of financial statement for publicly traded companies, preferably free. I have been using Yahoo Finance but think there might be some issues.

For example when looking at AIG I found that [Yahoo showed Total Current Assets and Total Current Liabilities](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=AIG%20Balance%20Sheet&annual) are not correct. And that there are no Current Liabilities given at all to total myself.

**Edit:**
Checking out Morning Star I saw similar data for current assets/liabilities. It is possible that my issue has more to do with understanding some financial statements than Yahoo's data.

Answer (score 7):

If you're researching a publicly traded company in the USA, you can search the company [filings with the SEC.](http://edgar.sec.gov/) Clicking 'Filings' [should take you here.](http://edgar.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/webusers.htm)

Comment: I would like to mark this answer and @passing through's answer. I believe this answer is 'more correct' but both seem excellent.

Answer (score 1):

All websites pull Statement data line by line from central databases.  They get to choose which line items to pull, and sometimes they get the plus/minus wrong and sometimes the Statements they recreate don't add up.  Nothing you can do about it.  All the sites have problems.  I personally think the best is Morningstar eg http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=POT&region=can&culture=en-US

Use these summary sites at the start of your decision process, but later confirm the facts straight from the Edgar or Sedar for Cdn companies http://www.sedar.com/search/search_form_pc_en.htm

Answer (score 0):

The best source of financial statements would be from the company in question.

On corporate websites of public listed companies, you can find such financial statements uploaded in the **Investor's Relations** section of their website.

If their company does not have an online presence, another alternative would be to go to the website of the exchange the company is trading in (e.g. NYSE or NASDAQ) for financial data.

Answer (score 0):

You can access financial statements contained within 10K and 10Q filings using Last10K.com's mobile app: [Last10K.com/mobile](https://www.last10k.com/mobile)

Disclosure: I work for [Last10K.com](https://www.last10k.com)

[image]